# standalone presentation editor

Tags: presentation

I have a handful of systems with office 2010 starter, and that's good enough. I very *rarely* work on presentations, and it would be nice to have something to do quick edits, and optionally act as a viewer without needing to install a full suite of software I don't need.

Is there a standalone presentation editor in the vein of PowerPoint or Impress?

Only installing Impress seems wasteful since I have to install much of the OpenOffice backend as well. PowerPoint Viewer is fine unless I find I need to edit a slide - I'm aware of these alternatives.

Portable, or low-dependency software would be preferred. The question is primarily for Windows systems, and comparability with at least MS Office PowerPoint slides would be essential.

Would prefer free - as in beer or puppies (else I suppose I could just make the switch to office 365) . Not concerned about ideological purity of licences, since its windows.

Comment: What do you mean by standalone, though? LibreOffice in its entirety is kind of "stand-alone". Do you mean "small"? Then, how small? Perhaps "statically linked"? Or "low memory footprint"? Be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at Kingsoft Presentation? http://www.kingsoftstore.com/presentation-free.html it might fit your needs as it can be installed independently or as part of a whole office suite.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) on OOXML (Office Open XML), Microsoft's file format for presentations, lists various applications which support the format. Most, though not all of them are office suits (e.g. LibreOffice, KOffice, Calligra Office); some are text editors, but those would probably not support PowerPoint.

The page also indicates potential licensing issues, and issues with the standardization process of the format, which may or may not have been the cause for the relative dearth of support. I doubt you will find something slimmer than what is essentially an office-suite-without-the-other-apps for the task.